# GCDAsyncSocket connect to path

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, gcdasyncsocket

I'm currently trying to use GCDAsyncSocket library to connect to a remote host.
Remote host socket url is at ":/xxx/xxz".

If I connect with the method

`- (BOOL)connectToHost:(NSString *)host onPort:(uint16_t)port error:(NSError **)errPtr;`

I can't find a way to specify the path after the IPAddressPort, how can this be done?

Comment: Network sockets don't have a path. The path is part of some protocol layered on top of the socket, like HTTP.

Comment: So how can I send an http request to the host via Socket?

Comment: Well you would probably use a higher level framework like `NSURLConnection` rather than operating at the socket level, otherwise you would need to implement the whole HTTP protocol yourself.

Comment: Yes this is rather clear, but my question was regarding the GCDAsyncSocket library. The send message property doesn't have possibility to send `NSURLConnection` but only NSStrings

Comment: Yes, the GCDAsyncSocket library is a direct socket interface.  `NSURLConnection` supports HTTP/S amongst other protocols.  If you want to connect to a web server use something like `NSURLConnection`, not `GCDAsyncSocket`. If you wanted to use `GCDAsyncSocket` you would need to write code to send all of the strings that from the HTTP protocol e.g. `GET /some/path` plus all of the headers and other stuff.